# How to migrate Google Appengine Python runtime 2.7 to 3.7?

Tags: python, google-app-engine-python

I'm going to migrate Google Appengine Python runtime 2.7 to 3.7.
How can I achieve it seamless?

Comment: how about 2to3.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Understanding differences between Python 2 and Python 3 on the App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences), buried in the official docs, describes the challenges.  You will not be able to migrate seamlessly unless you do not use ndb, memcache, email, or most of the other APIs that made GAE-Std-Py27 a PaaS.  Most of these APIs are not available (yet?) in GAE-Std-Py3.